# Substitute Regex pattern with another pattern dynamically

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do the following in python, where I have a long pattern where I need to substitute a portion of the pattern dynamically

```
substitutions = [rgx1, rgx2]
pattern = start_pattern<dynamic_substitution>end_pattern
for substitution in substitutions:
   newpattern = start_pattern<substitution>end_pattern
```

Is there a way to do this in Python

Comment: What's "this"? Code which doesn't do what you want is a terrible way to explain what it is that you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you are wanting to do... or at least this is the way that I would do it.

- compile the regex patterns that you need
- add them to a list
- iterate through the list as required
- use the regex function that is appropriate for your needs eg. `findall, search, match` etc.

```py
import re

rgx1 = re.compile(r"insert regex pattern 1 here")
rgx2 = re.compile(r"insert regex pattern 2 here")

patterns = [rgx1, rgx2]

for pattern in patterns:
    match = pattern.findall("my_string")
    print(match)
```

Where `rgx1` and `rgx2` are the entire regex patterns that you want.

Alternatively, you could probably do something more **dynamic** like this, but it may get a bit confusing:

```py
import re

patterns=[]
for i in range(5):
    pattern = re.compile(f"\s{i}\s")
    patterns.append(pattern)
    
s = " 3 "

for p in patterns:
    match = p.search(s)
    if match:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not found this round")
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Not found this round
Not found this round
Not found this round
Found
Not found this round
```